# ¿Cómo funciona Replace realmente C++/CLI?

Tags: sql, sql-server, c++, visual-c++, cli

Mi pregunta se trata sobre por qué no puedo reemplazar una cadena por otra, ya lo he hecho pero ahora que añado símbolos parece no funcionar.

Tengo esta cadena `str = "update nombre_tabla set descripcion = '<algo>' where id = <id>"`

y cuando estoy haciendo un `for` quiero reemplazar lo que trae de información en las etiquetas

ejemplo: `row[i]->Cell[j]->Value->ToString()` Esto es igual a **"Sanatorio"** por ejemplo entonces tiene que quedar la cadena de la siguiente manera cuando hago esto

```
str = str->Replace("<" + cabecera + ">", row[i]->Cell[j]->Value->ToString());
"update nombre_tabla set descripcion = 'Sanatorio' where id = <id>"
```

Este es el código de mi problema

```
if (coneServer->estaConectado())
    {
        bar->Visible = true;
        bar->Maximum = tableCsv->Rows->Count;
        bar->Value = 0;
        this->Update();
        String^ query = txtSql->Text;
        for (int fil = 1; fil < tableCsv->Rows->Count; fil++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < tableCsv->Rows[fil]->Cells->Count; col++)
            {
                for each(String^ cabecera in encabezados)
                {
                    if (cabecera == tableCsv->Columns[col]->HeaderText)
                    {
                        //---- Pendiente buscar porque no puedo reemplazar por ejemplo [nombre] por el valor
                        //---- y si puedo reemplazar solo nombre por el valor
                        String^ valor = tableCsv->Rows[fil]->Cells[col]->Value->ToString();
                        query = query->Replace("<" + cabecera + ">", valor);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!coneServer->ejecutarScriptSql(query))
            {
                MessageBox::Show(coneServer->getErrorMsg());
                if (MessageBox::Show("¿Desea cancelar la operación?", "Confirmación", MessageBoxButtons::YesNo, MessageBoxIcon::Question) == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::Yes)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            bar->Value = fil;
            this->Update();
        }
        bar->Visible = false;
    }
```

Este es un ejemplo real de lo que deseo hacer
[image: Ejemplo real de lo que deseo hacer]
El código en depurandolo antes de reemplazar cadenas
[image: Código en ejecución]
Después de supuesta mente reemplazar, a veces funciona y a veces no, no entiendo porque
[image: Reemplazar]